# application creating muant handles and never frees them

Tags: windbg, handle, resource-leak

My c++ application is creating mutant handles. I couldn't find where the handle is being created, so I used Windbg and with `!htrace`. It doesnt give the exact function name. All my symbol files are loaded and the application is built in debug mode.

`!htrace` shows open handles but the exact function where the handle is been opened,it doesnt show.
The trace looks like this

```
Handle = 0x00000d34 - OPEN
Thread ID = 0x00003670, Process ID = 0x00004748

0x77a0473c: ntdll!ZwCreateMutant+0x0000000c
0x75d7a0cd: KERNELBASE!CreateMutexExW+0x0000005e
0x75d7bb94: KERNELBASE!CreateMutexExA+0x0000002f
0x75d7bb5c: KERNELBASE!CreateMutexA+0x0000001d
```

Is there any alternative way to debug this issue?

Comment: What app?? which snippet?

Comment: This is a shot in the dark. FPO optimizations interfere with VerifierFlags like htrace that perform stack trace collection. Can you try this on a debug build of your project, or maybe turn optimizations off?

Comment: I turned off all the optimizations and the application is built in Debug mode only.I ran a sample with handle leaks, that sample is giving the full stack trace.FPO optimisations are turned off also.

Comment: if you are building it then setting a breakpoint on CreateMutexA and variants should show you the callstack